# How do I call a method from my uiviewcontroller in a utility nsobject class

Tags: objective-c, methods, uiviewcontroller, import, nsobject

How do I import a method from my uiviewcontroller to a utility class of nsobject (which I use in the viewcontroller to call common methods?) I have a large number of view controllers that need to call the same method.

Do I need to use NSInvocation? Should I use something different like protocols and delegates?

Without access to the method by the utility class I will just get "NSInvalidArgumentException"

This is the basic structure I need to use.

utilityClass - .h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface utilityClass : NSObject
- (void) swipeLoad: (UIView*)myview;

@end
```

.m

```
#import "utilityClass.h"

@implementation utilityClass

- (void) swipeLoad: (UIView*) myview
{
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *oneFingerSwipeRight =
    [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(oneFingerSwipeRight:)];
    [oneFingerSwipeRight setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];
    [myview addGestureRecognizer:oneFingerSwipeRight];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *oneFingerSwipeLeft =
    [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(oneFingerSwipeLeft:)];
    [oneFingerSwipeLeft setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
    [myview addGestureRecognizer:oneFingerSwipeLeft];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *twoFingerSwipeRight =
    [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(twoFingerSwiperight:)];
    [twoFingerSwipeRight setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];
                twoFingerSwipeRight.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2;
    [myview addGestureRecognizer:twoFingerSwipeRight];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *twoFingerSwipeLeft =
    [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(twoFingerSwipeLeft:)];
    [twoFingerSwipeLeft setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
    twoFingerSwipeLeft.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2;
    [myview addGestureRecognizer:twoFingerSwipeLeft];
            }

@end
```

view controller - .h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "utilityClass.h"

@class utilityClass;

@interface viewController : UIViewController
{
   utilityClass *utilityClass;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) utilityClass*utilityClass;

@end
```

.m

```
#import "viewcontroller.h"

@interface viewcontroller ()

@end

@implementation viewcontroller

@synthesize utilityClass = _utilityClass;


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.utilityClass = [[utilityClass alloc] init];

    [self.utilityClass swipeLoad:self.view];

}

- (void)twoFingerSwiperight:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
                //[self another_method]
}

- (void)twoFingerSwipeLeft:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
                //[self another_method]
}

- (void)oneFingerSwipeRight:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
                //[self another_method]
}

- (void)oneFingerSwipeLeft:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    //[self another_method]
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you would be better off subclassing UIViewController and putting your swipe methods in there. Then make all of your view controllers a subclass of your new subclass (in the example below, your view controllers would be subclasses of `MyViewController`.

You would then get rid of your utility class altogether.

// MyViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@implementation MyViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

// MyViewController.m

```
@implementation MyViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *oneFingerSwipeRight =
    [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(oneFingerSwipeRight:)];
    [oneFingerSwipeRight setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:oneFingerSwipeRight];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *oneFingerSwipeLeft =
    [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(oneFingerSwipeLeft:)];
    [oneFingerSwipeLeft setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:oneFingerSwipeLeft];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *twoFingerSwipeRight =
    [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(twoFingerSwiperight:)];
    [twoFingerSwipeRight setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];
    twoFingerSwipeRight.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:twoFingerSwipeRight];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *twoFingerSwipeLeft =
    [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(twoFingerSwipeLeft:)];
    [twoFingerSwipeLeft setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
    twoFingerSwipeLeft.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:twoFingerSwipeLeft];
}

- (void)oneFingerSwipeRight:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    // Your code here
}

- (void)oneFingerSwipeLeft:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    // Your code here
}

- (void)twoFingerSwiperight:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    // Your code here
}

- (void)twoFingerSwipeLeft:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    // Your code here
}

@end
```

Also, one side note. It's recommended that you start class names with a capital letter, and start variable and functions with a lowercase letter. It helps make your code much more readable.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even think of making a subclass of the UIViewcontroller. It worked like a charm. 

(I had changed my punctuation just for the example here.)

I would still like to figure out how to pass methods.